# SSMS 2012 BULK INSERT string that sometimes contains quotes

Tags: sql, insert, bulk

Trying to BULK INSERT a tab delimited .txt file with a number of columns.

The one giving me issues is just a text string. It sometimes contains quotation marks within the string. Like:

```
Joseph "Joe" Smith
```

when I bulk insert, that field ( as varchar(100)) will get inserted like

```
"Joseph ""Joe"" Smith"
```

I'm sure the answer is fairly simple, but all my searches turn up issues with quotation-delimited fields, and that's not my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on what your expected results are.

If you want to remove the quotes completely (i.e. it gets inserted as 'Joseph Joe Smith') then you will need to create a format file and specify it in your bulk insert statement.

The following link will have some more information on what a format file is and how to create/use one:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file.aspx

If you want the value to be true to what the input value is (i.e. 'Joseph "Joe" Smith'), then your best bet is to keep what you have an follow it up with an update statement and use the REPLACE function. Since you have double quotes, it should be relatively simple update statement.

```
Update YourTable
Set Name = REPLACE(Name, '""', '"')
```